# Powershell regex group : how do I get all subgroups 2

Tags: powershell

I want to extract file1, file2 I know how to do this in javascript, I'm lost in Powershell, I can only extract the whole second match following that tut https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/regular-expressions-regex-grouping-regex/, what's the syntax ?

```
  $regex = '(.+\\)*(.+)\.(.+)$'
  $data = @'
  "C:\test\file1.txt"
  "C:\test\file2.txt"
  '@
  [RegEx]::Matches($data,$regex).value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using `-match` and the `$matches` automatic variable to retrieve capture group values:

```
$data = @'
"C:\test\file1.txt"
"C:\test\file2.txt"
'@

$data -match '\\([^.\\]+)\.[\s\S]+?\\([^.\\]+)\.'

write-host $matches[1]    # file1
write-host $matches[2]    # file2
```

Comment: This fails for a valid path like `C:\te.st\file1.foo.txt`.

Comment: @zett42 Valid but contrived and beside the point. The question is mainly about getting the value of capture groups not matching any base name. Your own regex assumes the filename has a `.` in it and that it is followed by `"` and that the surrounding string has only paths in it, etc. To make it explicit, my regex is only intended to capture the first two substrings that are bookended by ``\`` and `.` and that do not contain any `.` or ``\`` within them.

Comment: Point taken. Cheers! (I had already upvoted btw.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could do it using the call to [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-matches(system-string)):

```sh
$data = @'
"C:\test\file1.txt"
"C:\test\file2.txt"
'@

$regex = [regex] '(.+\\)*(?<base>.+)\.(.+)'
$regex.Matches($data).ForEach{ $_.Groups['base'] }.Value

# Results in:
# file1
# file2
```

However since you're dealing with paths, I would personally recommend you to use [`FileInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0) to parse them. In this example, we can use the [String `.Trim(Char)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0#system-string-trim(system-char)) to remove the *leading* and *trailing* `"` from each path and the [`-as` Type Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) to safely convert the strings into `System.IO.FileInfo` instances.

```sh
$data = (@'
"C:\test\file1.txt"
"C:\test\file2.txt"
'@ -split '\r?\n').Trim('"') -as [IO.FileInfo[]]

$data.BaseName
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness another RegEx solution:

```sh
$data = @'
"C:\te.st\file1.txt"
"C:/test/file2.foo.txt"
'@

[regex]::Matches($data, '[^\\/]+(?=\.[^\\/]+\")').Value
```

Output:

```text
file1
file2.foo
```

The RegEx uses a [positive lookahead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions#lookahead-assertions) `(?=)` to assert that an extension follows, without capturing it.

Detailed explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SAOHGB/3).

I still think that the [`FileInfo` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72331933/7571258) is more robust and easier to maintain. It took me much longer to get the RegEx right than simply splitting and converting to `FileInfo` would have taken.